# Permission of DVD device file not being retained when machine is rebooted

Tags: fedora, devices, non-root-user, dvd

I am using Linux Fedora 4 and would like a non-root user to be able to write to DVDs using the DVD drive.

I was able to do this by adding write access to the group of the device file `/dev/scd0` and have added the user to the relevant group. However, whenever the machine is rebooted, the device file reverts back to its original permissions.

How can I configure it so that the permission stays the way I want it to?

I tried creating a file called `11-local.rules` in the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory with the following contents:

```
KERNEL=="scd0", MODE="0660"
```

But this did not help. The permission stays the way it is.

Comment: Until you get a proper solution, you can put the commands to change the permissions on startup in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Am I reading this right? Fedora 4? As in Fedora Core 4?

Comment: @slm: Yes, it is Fedora Core 4. I need to work with a legacy system and there isn't plans to upgrade because the project is at an end-of-life support stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try the following:***

```
# echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="scsi", KERNEL=="scd[0-9]", ATTRS{type}=="5" GROUP="optical", MODE="0666"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/80-cdrom.rules

test the rule

# udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sr0) 2>&1

load the rule

# udevadm control --reload-rules
```

***Update***

Looks like FC4 udev predated udevadm. I pulled up a tarball of udev-058-1 that shipped with FC4 and your 50-udev.rules relevant to dvd should look similar to this:

```
# old compat symlinks with enumeration
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*",     SYMLINK="cdrom%e"
KERNEL=="scd[0-9]*",        SYMLINK="cdrom%e"
KERNEL=="pcd[0-9]*",        SYMLINK="cdrom%e"

# do not seperate the next 2 lines!!
KERNEL=="hd[a-z]", BUS=="ide", SYSFS{removable}=="1", PROGRAM=="/etc/udev/scripts/ide-media.sh %k", RESULT=="floppy",  SYMLINK="floppy%e", NAME{ignore_remove, all_partitions}="%k"

KERNEL=="hd[a-z]", BUS=="ide", SYSFS{removable}=="1", RESULT=="cdrom", SYMLINK="cdrom%e"

KERNEL=="hd[a-z]", BUS=="ide", SYSFS{removable}=="1", PROGRAM=="/etc/udev/scripts/check-cdrom.sh %k DVD", SYMLINK="dvd%e"
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM=="/etc/udev/scripts/check-cdrom.sh %k DVD", SYMLINK="dvd%e"

KERNEL=="hd[a-z]", BUS=="ide", SYSFS{removable}=="1", PROGRAM=="/etc/udev/scripts/check-cdrom.sh %k CD-R", SYMLINK="cdwriter%e"
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM=="/etc/udev/scripts/check-cdrom.sh %k CD-R", SYMLINK="cdwriter%e"

KERNEL=="hd[a-z]", BUS=="ide", SYSFS{removable}=="1", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/scripts/check-cdrom.sh %k DVD-R", SYMLINK="dvdwriter%e"
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM=="/etc/udev/scripts/check-cdrom.sh %k DVD-R", SYMLINK="dvdwriter%e"

# rename sr* to scd*
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", BUS=="scsi", NAME="scd%n"
KERNEL=="hd[a-z]*", BUS=="ide", SYSFS{removable}=="1",  NAME{ignore_remove}="%k"
```

Try changing the line before last above that renames sr to scd to this and reboot.

```
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", BUS=="scsi", NAME="scd%n", MODE="0666"
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. The `udevadm` command also seems to be not available under FC4. While doing a search about this, I stumbled across this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504707/linux-udev-rule-does-not-appear-to-work) from the StackOverflow site with a very similar problem. Will give custom usermaps a try when I get the time.

Comment: Excellent! Your updated anwser works. Thank you very much for the help. You may want to update your answer to add a comma before the `MODE="0666"` part at the line you told me to change to aid in copy-and-paste.